# Making a Div display across the entire browser with CSS and html

Tags: html, css, position

This question has been asked here before, yes. But none of the answers seem to work for me and what I am trying to do.

I need a div to display across the entire browser. So far, I have this.

HTML

```
<body>
        <div id="header">My Website</div>
        <div id="games">Video Games</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#games {
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

So, `top:0, left:0`, and `position:absolute` are what get my div to span across the entire page. What's the problem?

My `#games div` is hidden behind my `#header div`. I am relatively new to `html` and `css`, and when I started learning divs, they would display right next to each other or right below and on top one another.

When I take out `position:absolute`, the `#games div` drops below the `#header div`, but then the header div only goes to the edge of the page's left and right side, and the top. I want it to go all the way to the edge, with no space in between the div and the browser sides, AND have my `#games div` naturally display underneath.

Note that I know that I can adjust the `#games` div's top-margin, but I wanted to know if there was a way to have it naturally sit underneath the `#header div`.

What can I do to make it so that my #games div is not naturally hidden behind the `#header div`, and sits just below?

Comment: Try `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: Why Are you Using position: absolute; ?

Comment: Because when I do not, there is white space between the edges of the browser and my #header div. It was one of the very few things I came across that made my div go across the entire browser, but then it throws my other divs off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
    <div id="main_wrap">
        <div id="header">My Website</div>
        <div id="games">Video Games</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#main_wrap {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;

}

#header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}

#games {
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked because of `body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }` This is great.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to do it like this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UKM62/):

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}

#header {
   height: 80px;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}

#games {
   height: 40px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute;` This tells the browser that whatever is going to be positioned should be removed from the normal flow of the document and will be placed in an exact location on the page.

so it means in your CSS you not really need to use `position:absolute` because by default when you will put div in `html` document it will start from `top, left`.

> Note: you should think about using `position:absolute` in worst case scenario and if still need to use please make sure parent `div` should be `position:relative`.

```
#header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
  /*  top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;*/
}
```